# Advantages of using a JSON string in the POST body as opposed to using key/value pairs in the POST body

Tags: api, http, web-applications

What are the advantages of using a JSON string in the POST body as opposed to using key/value pairs in the POST body? It seems like there are a lot of API's out there that do it.

Example of what I mean: user={"username":"bob", "age":1} vs username=bob&age=1 in the POST form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a JSON string, you just have to encode/decode your object and are ready to go. This especially useful when using multiple platforms.

Also, when you want to add new values/fields to your request, you just add it to the JSON object, instead of having to add extra validations in multiple files, possibly breaking code already works.

Another thing I can think of is that when using JSON you can code one single component with the only purpose of send/receive data, where you declare the function that will receive the decoded JSON and do whatever it wants with it. That way, you don't repeat code and let every function/class/file/whatever do the specific functionality it's meant to.

Comment: When you say encode/decode, is it the same as serialize/deserialize? or are you talking about url-encoding?

Comment: Yeah, by encode/decode I mean converting JSON->Object and Object->JSON.